# Ethereum Smart Contract for crowdsale with KYC verification

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

I have created the ERC20 token. I am looking to do a crowdsale with KYC. Is there any tool for crowdsale or demo project that uses KYC so I can learn about it?

Answer (score 2):

TokenMarket offers KYC services for token sales. We have open source smart contracts and Python based test suite for both presale and main sale use cases.

As the smart contract themselves are compilicated, I am skipping copy-pasting them here and linking to the well commented source code here:

https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/KYCCrowdsale.sol

https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/KYCPresale.sol

KYC itself is manual labour intensive process and will cost several US dollars per buyer, even done through a service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look for an API that ask ID and offer kyc verification (Affirm look great).

I would then code the api so each unferified wallet in my dapp need minimum verification, uprade limits etc.

Comment: if you have any learning materials or demo projects regarding KYC for crowdsale. so I can look through it for learning

Comment: Sorry not, there is plenty of resources out there and here.